# How to register manual backup for AWS Elastic search?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I am trying to backup my elasticsearch index to S3 bucket in a folder. I am using the following code to register the path:

```
from boto.connection import AWSAuthConnection
```

class ESConnection(AWSAuthConnection):

```
def __init__(self, region, **kwargs):
    super(ESConnection, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self._set_auth_region_name(region)
    self._set_auth_service_name("es")

def _required_auth_capability(self):
    return ['hmac-v4']
```

if **name** == "**main**":

```
client = ESConnection(
        region='us-east-1',
        host='search-weblogs-etrt4mbbu254nsfupy6oiytuz4.us-east-1.es.a9.com',
        aws_access_key_id='my-access-key-id',
        aws_secret_access_key='my-access-key', is_secure=False)

print 'Registering Snapshot Repository'
resp = client.make_request(method='POST',
        path='/_snapshot/weblogs-index-backups/test_dir',
        data='{"type": "s3","settings": { "bucket": "es-index-backups","region": "us-east-1","role_arn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/MyElasticsearchRole"}}')
body = resp.read()
print body
```

For the given path, I get the error:
No handler found for uri [/_snapshot/weblogs-index-backups/test_dir] and method [POST]

Any advice, please.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1) Create an IAM policy and add attach it to a role:
An example Role looks like the following:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "es.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

An example policy like this one should be attached to previous role:

```
 {
    "Version":"2012-10-17",
    "Statement":[
        {
            "Action":[
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Effect":"Allow",
            "Resource":[
                "arn:aws:s3:::es-index-backups"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Action":[
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "iam:PassRole"
            ],
            "Effect":"Allow",
            "Resource":[
                "arn:aws:s3:::es-index-backups/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

2) Registering a Snapshot Directory

As an IAM user with access to the new role, you must register the snapshot directory with Amazon Elasticsearch Service before you take manual index snapshots. This one-time operation requires that you sign your AWS request with the IAM role that grants permissions to Amazon ES.

Save the following sample Python code and modify the following values:
region: The AWS region where you created the snapshot repository
endpoint: The endpoint for your Amazon ES domain
aws_access_key_id: IAM credential
aws_secret_access_key: IAM credential
path: The location of the snapshot repository

Note: The Python client requires the boto package be installed on the computer where you will register your snapshot repository.

```
from boto.connection import AWSAuthConnection

class ESConnection(AWSAuthConnection):

    def __init__(self, region, **kwargs):
        super(ESConnection, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self._set_auth_region_name(region)
        self._set_auth_service_name("es")

    def _required_auth_capability(self):
        return ['hmac-v4']

if __name__ == "__main__":

    client = ESConnection(
            region='us-east-1',
            host='search-weblogs-etrt4mbbu254nsfupy6oiytuz4.us-east-1.es.a9.com',
            aws_access_key_id='my-access-key-id',
            aws_secret_access_key='my-access-key', is_secure=False)

    print 'Registering Snapshot Repository'
    resp = client.make_request(method='PUT',
            path='/_snapshot/weblogs-index-backups',
            data='{"type": "s3","settings": { "bucket": "es-index-backups","region": "us-east-1","role_arn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/MyElasticsearchRole"}}')
    body = resp.read()
    print body
```

Once the S3 repository is registered, you will be able to manually take and restore snapshots using curl. As example:

To manually take a snapshot:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://<Elasticsearch_domain_endpoint>/_snapshot/snapshot_repository/snapshot_name'
```

To manually restore a snapshot:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://search-weblogs-abcdefghijklmnojiu.us-east-1.a9.com/_snapshot/weblogs-index-backups/snapshot_1/_restore'
```

Note: You cannot restore a snapshot of your indices to an Amazon ES cluster that already contains indices with the same names. Currently, Amazon ES does not support the Elasticsearch _close API, so you must use one of the following alternatives:
Delete the indices on the same Amazon ES domain, then restore the snapshot
Restore the snapshot to a different Amazon ES domain

Comment: I am unable to register the snapshot repo. I made the Role and policy as here (same as documentation), but getting this error:
{"Message":"User: arn:aws:iam::<acc_ID>:user/<user_with_role_Access> is not authorized to perform: es:ESHttpPost on resource: elasticsearch"}

Comment: so I guess something is wrong with your iam role, elasticsearch policy - are you using iam policy with your cluster ? or your script, maybe post a new question with all the your scripts/policy detalis, it will be much easier to help.

Comment: Found it, was the ES access policy, was limiting IPs. Thank you!

Comment: ps: note that the code in the answer uses 'PUT' instead of 'POST' as in the aws documentation, I managed to run with 'POST'

Comment: When running the python script I get this error:
`{"error":"Content-Type header is missing","status":406}`. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Use boto3 and request module and python 3.7
Save the following sample Python code as a Python file, such as register-repo.py. The client requires the AWS SDK for Python (Boto3), requests and requests-aws4auth packages. The client contains commented-out examples for other snapshot operations.

```
import boto3
import requests
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth

host = '' # include https:// and trailing /
region = '' # e.g. us-west-1
service = 'es'
credentials = boto3.Session().get_credentials()
awsauth = AWS4Auth(credentials.access_key, credentials.secret_key, region, service, session_token=credentials.token)

# Register repository

path = '_snapshot/my-snapshot-repo-name' # the Elasticsearch API endpoint
url = host + path

payload = {
  "type": "s3",
  "settings": {
    "bucket": "s3-bucket-name",
    # "endpoint": "s3.amazonaws.com", # for us-east-1
    "region": "us-west-1", # for all other regions
    "role_arn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/TheSnapshotRole"
  }
}

headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}

r = requests.put(url, auth=awsauth, json=payload, headers=headers)

print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)

# # Take snapshot
#
# path = '_snapshot/my-snapshot-repo/my-snapshot'
# url = host + path
#
# r = requests.put(url, auth=awsauth)
#
# print(r.text)
#
# # Delete index
#
# path = 'my-index'
# url = host + path
#
# r = requests.delete(url, auth=awsauth)
#
# print(r.text)
#
# # Restore snapshot (all indices except Kibana and fine-grained access control)
#
# path = '_snapshot/my-snapshot-repo/my-snapshot/_restore'
# url = host + path
#
# payload = {
#   "indices": "-.kibana*,-.opendistro_security",
#   "include_global_state": false
# }
#
# headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
#
# r = requests.post(url, auth=awsauth, json=payload, headers=headers)
#
# # Restore snapshot (one index)
#
# path = '_snapshot/my-snapshot-repo/my-snapshot/_restore'
# url = host + path
#
# payload = {"indices": "my-index"}
#
# headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
#
# r = requests.post(url, auth=awsauth, json=payload, headers=headers)
#
# print(r.text)
```